# How can I use napms() in ncurses

Tags: c++, function, delay, game-development, ncurses

I'm trying to create a game in c++ with ncurses library. When I shot a bullet with the player I have to use the napms() function to draw the bullet movement, but the player can't move because of the napms() function. How can I fix that? I have to use the thread or there is a function that can help me for that?
Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 2):

The `poll()` / `select()` approach is popular, but -- unless you really need to check for non-curses input in the same loop -- I suggest that you instead look into a purely curses-based approach, built around `halfdelay()` or `timeout()`. You could also simply use `napms()` with a shorter delay, in a loop together with `getch()`, in `nodelay()` mode. For example, if you wanted to update the bullet every half-second, then instead of calling `napms(500)`, you might call `napms(50)` ten times -- checking the input after each time, allowing the player to respond -- and only then update the bullet.

(My bias here: If you stick to curses calls, your program will be easily portable to other implementations like PDCurses, which it won't be if you go the `poll()` / `select()` route.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you don't use `napms` with ncurses. You use no-delay mode and `poll()`. You start by using `nodelay()` to put ncurses into no-delay mode (see `ncurses` documentation for more information).

If you read `getch()` manual page, you will find it explained how in no-delay mode `getch` never blocks, but immediately returns `ERR` if no key has been pressed.

At this point you can use `poll()` or `select()` to wait for a key to be pressed, with an explicit timeout. That's your delay in milliseconds. You will have to add a little bit of logic to determine what should be done.

Your overall logic should be as follows:

1. Call `getch`
2. If `getch` returns a key, do whatever you want with it then go to step 1.
3. Only if `getch` returns ERR: calculate whether it's now time to do whatever else your program needs to do, like drawing your bullet. It's entirely possible that you have already waited the prescribed number of milliseconds since the last time your bullet was drawn. Afterwards go to step 1.
4. Only if your program reached a conclusion that it's not yet time to draw the bullet, calculate how much you need to wait before something needs to be done in step 3.
5. `poll()` or `select()` for the prescribed interval of time. Then go back to step 1.

So, for example, when you start from the beginning, `getch` gives you bupkis, then you decide that you just drew your bullet and you need to draw your bullet again in 100 milliseconds. You `poll()`, and after you wake up you have something from `getch`, and you work on that. Then whenever you end up back in step 5 you determine that the bullet was drawn 75 milliseconds ago (`poll()` returned because there's now something to be `getch`-ed, it did not time out, and after processing a key you consult the wall clock and see that it's now 75 milliseconds later) so you now `poll()` for 25 more milliseconds.

Comment: If I need to make an enemy movement at the same time with the player movement and the player shoots, you advice me to use getch and poll anyway?

Comment: It doesn't matter what specific action needs to be taken, the general approach is exactly the same, this is called an event loop: 1) Figure out what action needs to be taken now, whether one player moves, or one player shoots, or five players move and seven players shoot, if that's what needs to happen now, then it happens, if there's a key that's been pressed, do that too 2) If nothing needs to happen now, calculate when the next scheduled event will happen, 3) `poll()` for all of your input sources, using the calculated timeout. Go back to step 1. The End.